# No puedo acceder a phpmyadmin y el contenedor me da un error

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Esta es la imagen de mi contenedor actual https://gyazo.com/ae7423468c16664cd90bc774235f6dbf
como veis, abajo me da un extraño error que no sé si es normal que salga... en cualquier caso, no puedo acceder a phpmyadmin (problema del cual, creé un post anteriormente, pero me dieron una solución que corrigiera el error).

Esta es la imagen de mi archivo config:
https://gyazo.com/bb43bf7c30410105fbc3e2a86c8d9821

Answer (score 0):

El archivo php no influye en lo siguiente que comentaré.
Tienes alguna aplicación que trabaja en puerto 80 sin saberlo y está bloqueando que a apache para que no pueda iniciarse sobre ese puerto.
Usa la comanda siguiente en un terminal en modo administrador
`netstat -anob` esto te ayudará a saber que app te ocupa el puerto 80. Si no fuera el puerto 80 publica el resultado editando la pregunta.

Para la segunda pregunta obtienes un error por culpa del primero, un saludo